# How to calculate complementary color correctly in Sass?

Tags: sass

I am trying to get the complementary color in Sass correctly. I am aware of the helper function provided here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#complement

I want to get the complmentary color for `#95F195`, and I tried to use the follow code:

```
@debug color.adjust(#95F195, $hue: 180deg);
```

It will log out `#f195f1`. But when I get the complementary color in a color wheel with [Adobe Color Wheel](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel) and [Paletton](https://paletton.com), I am getting `FF9E9E` instead of `#f195f1`. Why is that?

Comment: Just thoughts: Have you had a look at the various topics about 'Complementary Colors' and how they are generated in general? It is interesting and not 'exact' values. ;-/ Have you had a look as what SASS provides as an explanation? see [Quick Color with Sass](https://revelry.co/insights/design/quick-color-with-sass/). I suspect you may have to view it to check it is acceptable anyway? My knowledge of this topic is very limited. I just found your question interesting. :)

Comment: So from what I understand right now, a Complementary color is location in the opposite of the base color in the color wheel. To calculate that, I just need to increase the color by `180deg`. Unexpectedly the color I am getting is slightly off and I have no idea why.